# Change form inputs based on selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 fields: `publishers` in a radio-button, `cities name` in a drop-down list and `images` of news paper.

How it is possible when I select the radio button the city drop-down changes accordingly and when we select a particular city the image of news paper comes according to the city selected?

the code i am using is the code is working in first time when we select another publisher code doesnot work for images :

```
<html>
<title>index</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var listA =[{name:'Ahmedabad', value:'Ahmedabad'}, {name:'Banglore', value:'Banglore'}, {name:'Chennai', value:'Chennai'}, {name:'Delhi', value:'Delhi'}, {name:'Hyderabad', value:'hyderabad'}, {name:'Jaipur', value:'Jaipur'}, {name:'Kochi', value:'Kochi'}, {name:'Kolkata', value:'Kolkata'}, {name:'Lucknow', value:'Lucknow'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}, {name:'NaviMumbai', value:'NaviMumbai'}, {name:'Pune', value:'Pune'}, {name:'Thane', value:'Thane'}];

var listB = [{name:'Banglore', value:'Banglore'}, {name:'Delhi', value:'Delhi'}, {name:'Kolkata', value:'Kolkata'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}];

var listC = [{name:'Ahmedabad', value:'Ahmedabad'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}, {name:'Banglore', value:'Banglore'}, {name:'Pune', value:'Pune'}];

var listD = [{name:'Ahmednagar', value:'Ahmednagar'}, {name:'Aurangabad', value:'Aurangabad'}, {name:'Jalgaon', value:'Jalgaon'}, {name:'Kolhapur', value:'Kolhapur'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}, {name:'Nagpur', value:'Nagpur'}, {name:'Nashik', value:'Nashik'}, {name:'Pune', value:'Pune'}];

var listE = [{name:'Delhi', value:'Delhi'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}, {name:'Lucknow', value:'Lucknow'}, {name:'Ghaziabad', value:'Ghaziabad'}, {name:'Noida', value:'Noida'}, {name:'faridabad', value:'Faridabad'}, {name:'Gurgaon', value:'Gurgaon'}];

var listF = [{name:'Delhi', value:'Delhi'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}, {name:'Lucknow', value:'Lucknow'}, {name:'Ghaziabad', value:'Ghaziabad'}, {name:'Noida', value:'Noida'}, {name:'faridabad', value:'Faridabad'}, {name:'Gurgaon', value:'Gurgaon'}];

var listG = [{name:'Ahmedabad', value:'Ahmedabad'}, {name:'Nav Gujrat Et Wealth', value:'Nav_Gujrat_Et_Wealth'}];

var listH = [{name:'Delhi', value:'Delhi'}, {name:'Mumbai', value:'Mumbai'}, {name:'Lucknow', value:'Lucknow'}, {name:'Ghaziabad', value:'Ghaziabad'}, {name:'Noida', value:'Noida'}, {name:'faridabad', value:'Faridabad'}, {name:'Gurgaon', value:'Gurgaon'}];



$(document).ready( function() {
$("input[name='chk']").on('change',function() {

if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'toi')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listA, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
});
}


else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'tet')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listB, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}
else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'mirror')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listC, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}

else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'mht')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listD, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}
else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'nbt')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listE, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}
else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'eis')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listF, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}
else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'ngs')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listG, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}
else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'vke')
{
$('#describe').empty()
$.each(listH, function(index, value) {
$('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
}); 
}
else
{
}
});
});  

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
.header{  width:100%; border-bottom:4px solid #0099ff;}
.headerin{  width: 710px; margin:0 auto; }
.divOuter {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f9f9f9;
border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #ddd;
margin: 28px auto;
padding:50px 20px;
width: 710px;
}
.clr{ clear:both;}
.left_feilds{ float:left; width:275px;}
.left_right{ float:left;}
.forms{ float:left; margin:128px 0 0 0;}
#describe{ padding:3px 10px; width:150px; float:left;}
.logo{ float:left;}

.submit{ }

.submit input{ background:#d12f2f;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 5px; width:80px;margin-top:30px; margin-left:30px; }
.imgs{ margin:180px 0 0 0px; float:left;}

.footer{ width:100%; border-top:3px solid #0099FF;}
.footerin{ width:780px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
.footerin a{ text-decoration:none; color:#666666; font-size:14px;}

img{
float: right;
height: 150px;
margin: 10px -120px;
width: 120px;}

</style>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

function check_value(fieldvalue)
{    
switch(fieldvalue)
{
case 1:

document.getElementById("imagedest").innerHTML = "<img src='../../mayank         /change_images_by_dropdown/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg'>";
break;
case 2:
document.getElementById("imagedest").innerHTML = "<img src='../../mayank/change_images_by_dropdown/images/Desert.jpg'>"; 
break;

case 3:
document.getElementById("imagedest").innerHTML = "<img src='../../mayank/change_images_by_dropdown/images/Hydrangeas.jpg'>"; 
break;
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div class="headerin">
<div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/big_logo.png" /></a></div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>

<div class="divOuter">
<div class="left_feilds">

<p><input type="radio" id="class" name="chk" value="toi" checked>The Times of India<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="tet">The Economic Times<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="mirror">Mirror<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="mht">Maharashtra Times<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="nbt">NavBharat Times<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="eis">Ei Samay<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="ngs">NavGujarat Samay<br/></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="vke">VijayKarnataka ePaper<br/></p>

<form action="insert_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input type="file" name="file" ></p>
<p><div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></div></p>

</div>

<div class="left_right">
<div class="forms">
<select id="describe">
<option name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1)'>Ahmedabad</option>
<option name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2)'>Banglore</option>
<option name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3)'>Chennai</option>
<option name="field" value="4" onclick='check_value(4)'>Delhi</option>
<option name="field" value="5" onclick='check_value(5)'>Hyderabad</option>
<option name="field" value="6" onclick='check_value(6)'>Jaipur</option>
<option name="field" value="7" onclick='check_value(7)'>Kochi</option>
<option name="field" value="8" onclick='check_value(8)'>Kolkata</option>
<option name="field" value="9" onclick='check_value(9)'>Lucknow</option>
<option name="field" value="10" onclick='check_value(10)'>Mumbai</option>
<option name="field" value="11" onclick='check_value(11)'>NaviMumbai</option>
<option name="field" value="12" onclick='check_value(12)'>Pune</option>
<option name="field" value="13" onclick='check_value(13)'>Thane</option>
</select>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="imgs">

<img src="images/knowMore.png" alt="" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="clr"></div>
<div id='imagedest'></div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<div class="footerin">
<p><a href="#">About Us</a> | <a href="#">Advertise with Us</a> | <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> |    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> </p>
<p>Copyright © 2014  • All rights reserved. </p>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the a sample code(html, js and the information), otherwise no one will help you...

Comment: you can use jQuery `change` function to achieve this. google it for details, also post what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

first add the  **onchange** event on to checkbox.
test the condition checkbox is checked or not
if checkbox is checked then get the value of checkbox and change cities name accrodingly

same thing for cities name to change images

Someone could help you better if you provide the code whatever you have tried

**here is a sample code you can get basic idea from**

```
<input name="check" type="radio" onclick="changeCities(this,1)"  value="1">having value 1
<input name="check" type="radio" onclick="changeCities(this, 2)"  value="2">having value 2
<input name="check" type="radio" onclick="changeCities(this, 3)"  value="3">having value 3

<br>
<br><br>

<select id="cities" onchange="getPhosts(this.value);">
    <option value="1">india</option>
    <option value="2">australia</option>
    <option value="3">america</option>
</select>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    function changeCities(thisObj, publisher) {
        var publisher = publisher || $(thisObj).val();
        // here get all the cities based on publishers
        // i am writing here some static data
        var cities = [{'id':'1', 'name':'dubai'}, {'id':'2', 'name':'arab'}];
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            options += "<option value='"+cities[i].id+"'>"  + cities[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        $('#cities').html(options);
    }

    function getPhosts(city){
        //same process like changeCities() for images here
    }
</script>
```